# Proper way of designing Controllers in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a question. Yesterday I started learning ASP.NET MVC3 and I made a blog where I can add, edit, delete posts and comment on those posts.

But I feel like I want to design it differently because I think I did it wrong.

I have two controllers. HomeController and BlogController and I think this is very wrong since I don't /add Blog, I add Post/Comment. Also I want my site consist not only from Blog itself.

What I want to make in this scenario

```
/Controllers
   HomeController.cs
   /Blog
      PostController.cs /* IndexAction - Show list of entries; DetailsAction - Show only one entry with comments under */
      CommentController.cs /* ListAction - Lists comments (not sure how to list them in Blog controller with PartialView yet...); AddAction - Add comment within Details of Post (again not sure if I can do this) */
   /SomeOtherThing
      SomeOtherController.cs /* Some random data from database like greeting in index page or whatever else not related to blog in any way */
   /Admin
      BlogController.cs /* For edit/delete blog data like comments/posts */
      SomeOtherController.cs /* For editing the other thing, not sure what for now */
      AccountsController.cs /* For editing accounts and such... */
```

I think that I want my controller hierarchy to look like this, but I am not sure if this is correct way of doing it. I rather start learning the right way then do it wrong way on my first project and then relearn how to do it correctly.

Also, about those Comments, is it good idea to make them in seperate controller? Because I want adding/showing in Post actions. For example `localhost/blog/post/1` will show post + form to add comment + list of comments. But I don't know how to do it yet though.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a small amount of controllers, leave all controllers in one folder. If you wish, you can 'simulate' a hierarchy by specifying routing in the global.asax file. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

When you foresee a large number of controllers in your site, use 'areas'. Areas provide a way to separate a large MVC Web application into smaller functional groupings. An area is effectively an MVC structure inside an application. See also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When working with projects that have a easily manageable number of controllers's I generally leave them all within the root controller folder. The teams I have been part of generally let the size and or complexity of the project determine if we need to create a "controller hierarchy". That said if you find it easier to conceptualize your project with the hierarchy you defined then go for it.

I would agree with your idea to move comments into their own self contained controller as they are a separate entity that can be designed and tested outside of a "blog post".